# why is my DFP OOP Ad not showing?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-dfp

Anyone serving video ads from rubicon project via dfp?

I have my code setup as below, and it seems I'm also getting some thing back from the ad server, but the oop video ad is not showing?

```
<head>
  ...     
  <!-- google tag serice -->
  <script src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
  <!-- End google tag service -->
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <!-- /net-work-id/ad-unit-code -->
  <div id='div-gpt-ad-x-0'>
    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function () {      
          googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/net-work-id/ad-unit-code', 'div-gpt-ad-x-0')
          .addService(googletag.pubads());
          googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
          googletag.enableServices();
          googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-x-0');
      });                        
    </script>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

A close eye at the network calls reveals 3 calls:

```
GET: http://entitlements.jwplayer.com/xxx.json
Response:
{
  "canPlayAds": true
}

GET: https://video-ads.rubiconproject.com/video/xx/xx/xx/xx/vast.xml?width=640&height=360:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VAST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd" version="2.0">
<Ad id="1">
    <InLine>
        <AdSystem>ad sys</AdSystem>
        <AdTitle>VPAID Wrapper</AdTitle>
        <Description>VAST for ad sys VPAID ad serving</Description>
        <Impression>
            <![CDATA[https://xxx]]>
        </Impression>
        <Creatives>
            <Creative sequence="1">
                <Linear>
                    <Duration>00:00:30</Duration>
                    <AdParameters>
                         < ![CDATA[{
                                    "host": "example.com",
                                    "path": "\/a\/api\/vast.xml",
                                    "assets_url": ":\/\/xxx.com\/video\/assets\/",
                                    "query_parameters": {
                                        "account_id": "xxx",
                                        "site_id": "xxx",
                                        "zone_id": "xxx",
                                        "size_id": "xxx",
                                        "width": "640",
                                        "height": "360"
                                    },
                                    "stats_base_url": "https:xxx",
                                    "emily_base_url": "https:xxx/usync.html",
                                    "emily_accts": ["xxx", ...],
                                    "whiteops_throttle": "10",
                                    "moat_partner_code": "xxx",
                                    "throttle_rate": {
                                        "moat": "0.05"
                                    },
                                    "protocol": "https"
                                }
                            ]] >
                    </AdParameters>
                    <MediaFiles>
                        <MediaFile apiFramework="VPAID" delivery="progressive" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360">
                            <![CDATA[https://example.com/video/xxx.swf]]>
                        </MediaFile>
                        <MediaFile apiFramework="VPAID" delivery="progressive" type="application/javascript" width="640" height="360">
                            <![CDATA[https://example.com/video/xxx.js]]>
                        </MediaFile>
                        <MediaFile apiFramework="VPAID" delivery="progressive" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360">
                            <![CDATA[https://example.com/video/xxx.swf]]>
                        </MediaFile>
                    </MediaFiles>
                </Linear>
            </Creative>
        </Creatives>
    </InLine>
</Ad>
```

Last call which I think happens inside `<iframe>` with query parameters including the list from the above response:

[image]

Response:

```
<iframe>
    https://optimized-by.rubiconproject.com/a/api/vast.xml?account_id=xx&..

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd">
   <!-- Code: psaNRF -->
</VAST>
```

Just `<!-- Code: psaNRF -->` inside the response.

Can anybody jump into my shoes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a `VAST` xml with a set of `VPAID` creatives that in turn load another `VAST` url (check out `AdParameters` options)
The second VAST url returns nothing (your second empty response) so nothing is displayed